# HTML - Centered transparent rectangle of certain width

Tags: html, css

I have a page like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m2fZs/210/)

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('http://freeseamlesstextures.com/images/40-dirty-paper-background-sml.jpg');
    font-family: "Arial CE", "Helvetica CE", Arial, sans-serif;color:orange
    }
```

with a repeated background image, but the overlaying text isn't very well legible.

I'd like to put a rectangle (of one color or possibly 50% transparent - maybe another small, half transparent png on repeat?) behind the text so it's easier to read - it should be as wide as the text (800px) and the height should be 100%.

Is that possible? Thanks.

EDIT: To be more clear, I'd like the dark (or semi-transparent) layer to go over the whole page, from top to bottom, so it's behind the logo and possibly the footer as well, not just where the text is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m2fZs/211/? Of course, separate all paragraphs properly...

Comment: As above, however I'd recommend not using opacity as it will also apply to the text. http://jsfiddle.net/m2fZs/212/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the text inside a div with some id and then apply css to that div.

HTML

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo-Logo.svg" ALT="" BORDER="0">
<br>
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec erat dolor, pulvinar eget erat id, gravida hendrerit nisl. Nunc nec laoreet mi. Donec posuere dui id diam semper, ut venenatis nibh tincidunt. Nulla blandit mattis nulla, sed rutrum metus convallis ut. Maecenas sed massa erat. Fusce augue erat, malesuada eget hendrerit et, viverra ac ligula. Donec eu mi ex. Aenean interdum magna ultrices massa convallis, sit amet varius tortor fringilla. In congue odio sapien.
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('http://freeseamlesstextures.com/images/40-dirty-paper-background-sml.jpg');
    font-family: "Arial CE", "Helvetica CE", Arial, sans-serif;color:orange
    }    

#content{
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.84);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/m2fZs/215/)

Comment: To change the transparency, you can change  0.84 in the background-color to any number you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks, your solution looks nice, and if I want to put the layer over the whole page, I can put the <div id="content"> for the whole <body>, right?

Comment: You have to use html content inside <body> tag

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code as per your requirements.

Made some changes to the css to make the logo appear in the center and added a footer.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <IMG SRC="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo-Logo.svg" ALT="" BORDER="0" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec erat dolor, pulvinar eget erat id, gravida hendrerit nisl. Nunc nec laoreet mi. Donec posuere dui id diam semper, ut venenatis nibh tincidunt. Nulla blandit mattis nulla, sed rutrum metus convallis ut. Maecenas sed massa erat. Fusce augue erat, malesuada eget hendrerit et, viverra ac ligula. Donec eu mi ex. Aenean interdum magna ultrices massa convallis, sit amet varius tortor fringilla. In congue odio sapien.</p>
    <p>Nam ut nisi varius, pretium nisl vitae, dignissim lectus. Donec vel tortor commodo, congue sem nec, lobortis neque. Pellentesque tortor elit, aliquam vel porttitor ac, luctus a dolor. Proin fringilla, orci id fermentum luctus, dolor felis convallis mauris, et finibus nunc nulla sed massa. Mauris pellentesque felis eget justo commodo tempor id eu magna. Ut auctor massa vel risus viverra lobortis. Aenean vitae turpis vel erat feugiat ullamcorper. In et erat neque. Nulla efficitur turpis nisl, non dictum leo ullamcorper vel. Vestibulum dignissim venenatis est eget cursus. Cras accumsan placerat luctus. Pellentesque elementum risus nisi, in imperdiet tortor iaculis non. Donec malesuada ut felis at vehicula. Proin quis lorem elit. Nunc at nulla convallis lacus euismod maximus convallis id mauris. Quisque rhoncus tincidunt malesuada.</p>
    <p>Praesent malesuada interdum pretium. In vulputate turpis fermentum dolor sodales, placerat feugiat nibh sollicitudin. Duis egestas, nisl ac mattis elementum, neque tellus sagittis magna, vitae aliquet justo ex id nulla. Suspendisse sit amet porta nunc. Nulla luctus cursus leo ut maximus. Nullam auctor justo eget eros pulvinar varius. Maecenas condimentum neque sit amet lacus rutrum faucibus. Fusce sodales mattis elementum. Morbi tempor purus felis, maximus viverra lorem venenatis ut. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum condimentum porta lorem. Maecenas nec placerat elit. Phasellus et nisi tincidunt, ullamcorper erat ut, mollis eros.</p>
    <p>Ut scelerisque, quam eu varius consectetur, ex lacus ornare turpis, vitae tempus ex dolor elementum neque. Donec sodales orci nulla, vel semper libero porta nec. Aliquam ut cursus ante. Proin rutrum commodo dui, et posuere purus cursus eget. Mauris egestas vel risus nec consequat. Quisque sit amet leo maximus nunc porta fermentum sit amet non justo. Donec accumsan iaculis suscipit. Phasellus rutrum venenatis neque, dapibus pellentesque eros finibus a. Aliquam tincidunt tortor et ipsum consequat placerat. Vivamus scelerisque libero quis mauris gravida, et tempor elit ultrices. Aenean accumsan porttitor placerat. Phasellus egestas maximus ligula, a imperdiet mi condimentum sit amet</p>
    <footer> <span>www.whatever.com &copy; 2015</span></footer>
</div>
```

css for img

```
img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

CSS for footer

```
footer {
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgb(90, 90, 90);
    margin-left: -10px;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Check this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPaoeQ?editors=110)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However, on some pages, there is just a short paragraph of text and it's seems unnecessary to have to scroll the min-height just for the footer... that's why I have a fixed footer like this - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x88pxyos/) - and somehow it doesn't work well when I move the whole #content div from the top by that 10px margin  :-/

Answer (score -1):

I updated some code.
[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/m2fZs/214/)

```css
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('http://freeseamlesstextures.com/images/40-dirty-paper-background-sml.jpg');
    font-family: "Arial CE", "Helvetica CE", Arial, sans-serif;color:orange
    }    

.text-container{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: OK, this text-container is nice (the padding is a nice touch), but I'd like the dark layer to go over the whole page, from top to bottom, so it's behind the logo and possibly the footer as well...

Comment: you can change the background image with the required opacity.